# If exists (select top 1 1 from table) in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

How to write the T-SQL below in SnowFlake

```
if exists (select top 1 1 from tableName)
```

This returns `true` or `false`

**Update**

I tried to run the `if` in the screenshot below in the Snowflake browser, but get the error:
[image]

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/if.html

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what select top 1 1 from ... does? (Will provide clarity for me + future readers)

Comment: @YaakovBressler It is just a way to help query engine to faster determine the result(access the first row(any) and return literal 1 instead of accessing actual column). For modern query optimizer it does not matter and it is the same as `IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM tablename)`

Comment: ^ I meant, to contextualize the Q. But also, very helpful @LukaszSzozda TY

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where you will use it:

```
create table tableName( id number);

SELECT  exists (select top 1 1 from tableName);
-- returns false

insert into tablename values (1 );

SELECT  exists (select top 1 1 from tableName);
-- returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct equivalent of `IF`:

```
-- SQL Server
if exists (select top 1 1 from tableName)
 -- come code
```

is an anonymous block with branch construct(Snwoflake Scripting):

```
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(select top 1 1 from tableName)) THEN
    -- some code
  END IF;
END;
```

If Classic WebUI is used then [Using Snowflake Scripting in SnowSQL and the Classic Web Interface](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(select top 1 1 from tableName)) THEN
    RETURN 1;
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Pls see my update, any idea for the error? This is why I thought I had the wrong syntax, but it is not.

Comment: @Pingpong Either switch to Snowsight or wrap the begin/end block with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Answer (score 0):

This expression evaluates `true` if (and only if) the table `tablename` contains any data (that is 1 or more rows).

```
IF EXISTS ( 
    SELECT TOP 1
        1
    FROM tablename
)
```

It should have the same effect as

```
IF EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM tablename
)
```

I don't know but I would expect Snowflake to be smart enough to do no more than determine if there are results in either case.

The second form is the common SQL idiom in my experience.